# javascript not running jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure how to title this but the problem is...
I have some jQuery lines that work ok, they are activated first when the page is loaded and then at the click inside a div.

I'm now trying to have the same code running on time intervals but it doesn't work at all nor outputs any error....

Any idea?
the website is built on WordPress and the script is running over a picture "slideshow"
you can check on http://demo.lavenderwp.com/nowland/

The code I used for time intervals is:

```
setInterval("myFunc()",100);

function myFunc()
{
$('#slider, .leftNav, .rightNav, .bottomNav').click(function()
        {
            $(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex <= 100;
                }).find('img').wrap('<div class="blue" />') .css({opacity: 0.75, border: "0px white solid"});

            $(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex <= 100;
                }).find('div.car').css({display: "none"});

            $(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex >= 100;
                }).find('img').css("background-color","") .css({opacity: 1, border: "15px white solid"});

            $(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex >= 100;
                }).find('div.car').css({display: "block"});
        });
}
```

Comment: You may need to delay running this code until the DOM finishes loading, unless you're calling this from some event on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `setInterval` (and any jQuery related code) within `$(function(){ });` so it only starts when the document is loaded. And as @tymeJV points out, you should pass the function without brackets.

Also, you do realise that the interval time is in milliseconds? Your `myFunc` runs 10 times a second. You also don't need to re-bind the `click` event. Just do it once and it'll be OK.

Comment: you can also use, $(document).ready(...) to initialize the interval.

Comment: `$(function(){ }); so it only starts when jQuery is loaded` - you mean "so it only starts when the DOM is loaded", right?

Comment: @Ian yes I did. I typed my answer too quickly it seems.

Comment: my mistake for copying the click event, I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: don't do this!

Why are you repeatedly attaching click event listeners ten times a second?!? This will rapidly run out of memory, unless jQuery is clever enough to attach them only once..

You should only have to attach the click events once. If the reason you're doing this is that the DOM elements you're attaching the listeners to are replaced during the slideshow, then use event delegation instead.

Or if the problem is simply that the event listeners don't get attached when the page is first loaded, then as others suggested, use `$(document).ready(myFunc);` or `$(myFunc);`.

Show more of your code - in particular the relevant HTML - and someone can give more specific suggestions.

Looking at your `myInit` code in more detail, the code in that function has a bit of repetition that would be best removed, and also there's an off-by-one error. What happens if one of your elements has a `z-index` of exactly 100? It passes *all* the `.filter()` tests. And also the indentation is a bit confusing.

Here's an example of how you could clean up that code:

```
function myFunc() {
    $('#slider, .leftNav, .rightNav, .bottomNav').click(function() {

        var $all = $(".contentHolderUnit");
        var $lower = $all.filter(function(i, el) {
            return el.style.zIndex <= 100;  // or should it be < 100 ?
        });
        var $upper = $all.not( $lower );

        $lower.find('img').wrap('<div class="blue" />').css({
            opacity: 0.75,
            border: "0px white solid"
        });

        $lower.find('div.car').css({
            display: "none"
        });

        $upper.find('img').css({
            backgroundColor: "",
            opacity: 1,
            border: "15px white solid"
        });

        $upper.find('div.car').css({
            display: "block"
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around your function as well as `()`:

```
setInterval(myFunc , 100);
```

Also, be sure to include this function after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`

You can read more about it here:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing guys!
Got it working, thanks a lot!

Final code is:

```
jQuery(function(){
setInterval(myFunc,100);
});

function myFunc()
{
jQuery(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex <= 100;
                }).find('img').wrap('<div class="blue" />') .css({opacity: 0.75, border: "0px white solid"});

            jQuery(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex <= 100;
                }).find('div.car').css({display: "none"});

            jQuery(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex >= 100;
                }).find('img').css("background-color","") .css({opacity: 1, border: "15px white solid"});

            jQuery(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) 
            {
                    return el.style.zIndex >= 100;
                }).find('div.car').css({display: "block"});
        }
```